# Make sure all callback return types are the same in typescript function

Tags: typescript

I want to implement a function to handle a return type the following way:

```js
export type Result<T, E = Error> = { ok: true; val: T } | { ok: false; err: E };

function handle<T, R = T | void>(
    r: Result<T>,
    success: (val: T) => R,
    handle: (err: Error) => R
): R
```

I want to make sure that both function outputs are either both `void` or both `T`.
I tried many type guards but `typeof` doesn't work as R is not a primitive.
I could check if R is a Union but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286) seems overly complicated for my usecase.

Is there a good way to to this?

Comment: Use overloads; instead of a generic parameter `R`, replace it with two overloads that each use `T` or `void`.

Comment: Oh no, I see the conundrum now. `void` means the return value won't be used so TypeScript won't try to infer the return type of the callbacks any further... And `undefined` doesn't seem to please TypeScript either...

Comment: A [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mxYnGW) so anyone else in the future can get started on this problem.

Comment: I didn’t even know that was another problem 